# Manipulate a tiff image file containing a Z stack with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an RGB tiff file containing a Z stack of 44 images. I want to open the file, convert it to grayscale, and save the resulting image as a new file.

The code I have right now is:

```
from PIL import Image
myimg = Image.open('1R - C1.tif')
myimg = myimg.convert('L')
myimg.save('1R - C1 BW.tif')
```

When I open the saved file, it contains only the first one of the 44 images in the stack. How do I manipulate and save the entire stack?